# How to creator a custom router in pwa magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3.1, pwa

**I want to create a custom router in pwa.**

I want to create blogs url. ( website.com/blogs )

so I can show all blogs list here.

Is anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: did you manage to find out more about this?

Answer (score 0):

Refer : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/webapi/custom-routes.html

```
<services xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_WebapiAsync:etc/webapi_async.xsd">
    <route url="V1/widgets" method="POST" alias="createWidget" />
    <route url="async/bulk/V1/widget" method="PUT" alias="asyncBulkUpdateWidgets"/>
    .........
</services>
```

This example redefines two routes:

All requests made on endpoint POST /createWidget will be forwarded to POST V1/widgets
All requests made on endpoint PUT /asyncBulkUpdateWidgets will be forwarded to PUT async/bulk/V1/widget

Thanks!!